# Saving images in a loop faster than multithreading / multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, image, multiprocessing

Here's a timed example of multiple image arrays of different sizes being saved in a loop as well as concurrently using threads / processes:

```
import tempfile
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from pathlib import Path
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2


def save_img(idx, image, dst):
    cv2.imwrite((Path(dst) / f'{idx}.jpg').as_posix(), image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 50, 50, 1))
    l2 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 50, 50, 1))
    l3 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10000, 50, 50, 1))
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    workers = 4
    t1 = perf_counter()
    for ll in l1, l2, l3:
        t = perf_counter()
        for i, img in enumerate(ll):
            save_img(i, img, temp_dir)
        print(f'Time for {len(ll)}: {perf_counter() - t} seconds')
        for executor in ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor:
            with executor(workers) as ex:
                futures = [
                    ex.submit(save_img, i, img, temp_dir) for (i, img) in enumerate(ll)
                ]
                for f in as_completed(futures):
                    f.result()
            print(
                f'Time for {len(ll)} ({executor.__name__}): {perf_counter() - t} seconds'
            )
```

And I get these durations on my i5 mbp:

```
Time for 100: 0.09495482999999982 seconds
Time for 100 (ThreadPoolExecutor): 0.14151873999999998 seconds
Time for 100 (ProcessPoolExecutor): 1.5136184309999998 seconds
Time for 1000: 0.36972280300000016 seconds
Time for 1000 (ThreadPoolExecutor): 0.619205703 seconds
Time for 1000 (ProcessPoolExecutor): 2.016624468 seconds
Time for 10000: 4.232915643999999 seconds
Time for 10000 (ThreadPoolExecutor): 7.251599262 seconds
Time for 10000 (ProcessPoolExecutor): 13.963426469999998 seconds
```

Aren't threads / processes expected to require less time to achieve the same thing? and why not in this case?

Comment: will it be the same if you use ex.map instead of submit?

Comment: Process and thread durations improve to be exactly equals to the for loop durations, which is pretty much the same issue.

Comment: i/o bound computations are _in general_ not sped up by multithreading. Threads provide the potential for more than one cpu to provide cycles at the same time. But It takes very little cpu effort to keep i/o channels completely full. Consequently, the potential for more cpu power isn't helpful.

Comment: So in this particular use case, do you mean that both multithreading and multiprocessing approaches are not necessary and it's better to use the for loop? if so, then what is the proper way to speed things up? concurrently or not

Comment: There are 100, 1000, and 10000 images being written, you're confusing the first dimension for the image size. I'm using the same logic in some text generation code which renders texts to images and save them. The example is just a simplified version. I mentioned running the examples on a i5 macbook pro.

Comment: It is surprising that the 4-worker versions are so much slower than the for-loop. Maybe the disk writes are competing with each other, so it isn't efficiently finishing one, before starting to write next. Imho, the best you can do is have two threads, one compressing jpg to a memory array, the other writing that memory array to disk. First thread enqueues, second thread dequeues. To avoid running out of memory, probably make first thread wait, if queue already has two entries. If the disk is keeping up, then you could have two threads creating memory arrays. But only one thread to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timings in the code are wrong because the timer `t` is not reset before testing the Pools. Nevertheless, the relative order of the timings are correct. A possible code with a timer reset is:

```py
import tempfile
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from pathlib import Path
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2


def save_img(idx, image, dst):
    cv2.imwrite((Path(dst) / f'{idx}.jpg').as_posix(), image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 50, 50, 1))
    l2 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 50, 50, 1))
    l3 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10000, 50, 50, 1))
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    workers = 4

    for ll in l1, l2, l3:
        t = perf_counter()
        for i, img in enumerate(ll):
            save_img(i, img, temp_dir)
        print(f'Time for {len(ll)}: {perf_counter() - t} seconds')
        for executor in ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor:
            t = perf_counter()
            with executor(workers) as ex:
                futures = [
                    ex.submit(save_img, i, img, temp_dir) for (i, img) in enumerate(ll)
                ]
                for f in as_completed(futures):
                    f.result()
            print(
                f'Time for {len(ll)} ({executor.__name__}): {perf_counter() - t} seconds'
            )
```

Multithreading is faster specially for I/O bound processes. In this case, compressing the images is cpu-intensive, so depending on the implementation of OpenCV and of the python wrapper, multithreading can be much slower. In many cases the culprit is CPython's GIL, but I am not sure if this is the case (I do not know if the GIL is released during the `imwrite` call). In my setup (i7 8th gen), Threading is as fast as the loop for 100 images and barely faster for 1000 and 10000 images. If `ThreadPoolExecutor` reuses threads, there is an overhead involved in assigning a new task to an existing thread. If it does not reuses threads, there is an overhead involved in launching a new thread.

Multiprocessing circumvents the GIL issue, but has some other problems. First, pickling the data to pass between processes takes some time, and in the case of images it can be *very* expensive. Second, in the case of windows, spawning a new process takes a lot of time. A simple test to see the overhead (both for processes and threads) is to change the `save_image` function by one that does nothing, but still need pickling, etc:

```py
def save_img(idx, image, dst):
    if idx != idx:
        print("impossible!")
```

and by a similar one without parameters to see the overhead of spawning the processes, etc.

The timings in my setup show that 2.3 seconds are needed just to spawn the 10000 processes and 0.6 extra seconds for pickling, which is much more than the time needed for processing.

A way to improve the throughput and keep the overhead to a minimum is to break the work on chunks, and submit each chunk to the worker:

```py
import tempfile
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from pathlib import Path
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
from cv2 import cv2


def save_img(idx, image, dst):
    cv2.imwrite((Path(dst) / f'{idx}.jpg').as_posix(), image)

def multi_save_img(idx_start, images, dst):
    for idx, image in zip(range(idx_start, idx_start + len(images)), images):
        cv2.imwrite((Path(dst) / f'{idx}.jpg').as_posix(), image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 50, 50, 1))
    l2 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 50, 50, 1))
    l3 = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10000, 50, 50, 1))
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    workers = 4

    for ll in l1, l2, l3:
        t = perf_counter()
        for i, img in enumerate(ll):
            save_img(i, img, temp_dir)
        print(f'Time for {len(ll)}: {perf_counter() - t} seconds')
        chunk_size = len(ll)//workers 
        ends = [chunk_size * (_+1)  for _ in range(workers)]
        ends[-1] += len(ll) % workers
        starts = [chunk_size * _  for _ in range(workers)]
        for executor in ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor:
            t = perf_counter()
            with executor(workers) as ex:
                futures = [
                    ex.submit(multi_save_img, start, ll[start:end], temp_dir) for (start, end) in zip(starts, ends)
                ]
                for f in as_completed(futures):
                    f.result()
            print(
                f'Time for {len(ll)} ({executor.__name__}): {perf_counter() - t} seconds'
            )
```

This should give you a significant boost over a simple for, both for a multiprocessing and multithreading approach.

Comment: And yet the multiprocessing has the worst timing. So, what do you suggest to speed up this operation? I don't think it's os specific, I tried on my mbp and ubuntu different machine, I get similar results. From what I see, both processes and threads are equally useless.

Comment: See my updated answer. The last piece of code shows a solution to your problem

Comment: my mistake, I guess I misplaced the `perf_counter()` call. I tried your updated solution and I guess it fixes the problem. Why threads have the best time though? ex: 7.372398026000001, 2.9415655140000005, and 6.112366614999999 for `for`, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and `ProcessPoolExecutor` respectively (n = 10000). Does this imply the GIL is released during `cv2.imwrite` call?

Comment: It implies that the GIL is not hold during the whole call, but it is released at some point (I am sure that it is released during I/O calls, but I can't tell if it released when the underlying OpenCV function is called)